# How to join with having in mysql?

Tags: mysql

All, I face a problem with join mysql. I want to get a result with count a unique amount of `staff_id` field using GROUP BY. If I run this query I got result as I want at one step.

```
SELECT id,staff_id,note,warning_date FROM tbl_warning GROUP BY staff_id HAVING (count(staff_id) > 0);
```

[image]

The next I want to join two more tables to get field such as `tbl_employment`.`com_id` as `comid`, `tbl_staff`.`name`, `tbl_staff`.`gender` but the result are duplicate.

`` `SELECT` `tbl_warning`.`id`, `tbl_warning`.`staff_id`, `tbl_warning`.`note`, `tbl_warning`.`warning_date`,`tbl_employment`.`com_id` as `comid`, `tbl_staff`.`name`, `tbl_staff`.`gender` FROM `tbl_warning` 
    JOIN `tbl_employment` ON `tbl_employment`.`staff_id` = `tbl_warning`.`staff_id` 
    JOIN `tbl_staff` ON `tbl_staff`.`id` = `tbl_warning`.`staff_id` 
    HAVING (SELECT `staff_id` FROM `tbl_warning` GROUP BY `staff_id` HAVING (count(staff_id) > 1)); ``

I want unique result same first screenshot.
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should join to a subquery which finds the matching staff by count:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.staff_id,
    t1.note,
    t1.warning_date,
    t2.com_id as `comid`,
    t3.name,
    t3.gender
FROM tbl_warning t1 
INNER JOIN tbl_employment t2
    ON t2.staff_id = t1.staff_id
INNER JOIN tbl_staff t3
    ON t3.id = t1.staff_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT staff_id
    FROM tbl_warning
    GROUP BY staff_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t
    ON t.staff_id = t2.staff_id;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I have created a report about Warning Letter. I want to get any staff who got twice or more warning. I have three tables. T_staff (store personal info such as name, gender, address,....), T_employment ( store employee info such as position, department,.....) and T_warning( store warning info such as staff_id, warning_date, & attachment). I want to count any staff who got twice or more warning with some info from T_staff and T_employment. Note: staff A warning add to T_warning. Staff A got warning again add to T_warning also.

Comment: Please provide sample data and also the expected output.  My answer should be working for you, barring something about your data which I don't know.

Comment: Your query I run -> https://imgur.com/a/uIaq7Xr Result I want ->https://imgur.com/a/1N0vCAu Sameple DB -> https://www77.zippyshare.com/v/70xwUV61/file.html